# D3 managing multiple classes for multiple chart labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When compiling multiple donut charts on one page, I noticed I'm getting some "artifacts" when appending the data labels. Snippet below:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  left: 50,
  bottom: 20,
  right: 20
};

var width = 300;
var arcSize = (6 * width / 100);
var innerRadius = arcSize * 3;

var extent = 1800;

var data2 = [
  [{
      value: (231 / extent * 100),
      marker: 231,
      label: "Collective",
      color: '#b8cce4',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (233 / extent * 100),
      marker: 233,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: '#95b3d7',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (45 / extent * 100),
      marker: 45,
      label: "Specific",
      color: '#4f81b9',
      neg: false
    },
  ],

  [{
      value: (171 / extent * 100),
      marker: 171,
      label: "Collective",
      color: '#b8cce4',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (1712 / extent * 100),
      marker: 1712,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: '#95b3d7',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (1 / extent * 100),
      marker: 1,
      label: "Specific",
      color: '#4f81b9',
      neg: false
    },
  ],

  [{
      value: (207 / extent * 100),
      marker: 207,
      label: "Collective",
      color: '#b8cce4',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (975 / extent * 100),
      marker: 975,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: '#95b3d7',
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (153 / extent * 100),
      marker: 153,
      label: "Specific",
      color: '#4f81b9',
      neg: false
    },
  ]


];


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 1100 + 100).attr('height', 1100 + 100);

var graphGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

for (var j = 0; j < (data2.length); j++) {

  var data = data2[j];

  var arcs = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + innerRadius).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - (width / 100) + innerRadius);
  });
  var arcsGrey = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + (innerRadius + ((arcSize / 2) - 2))).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - ((arcSize / 2)) + (innerRadius));
  });

  var pieData = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return [{
        value: obj.value * 0.75,
        arc: arcs[i],
        object: obj
      },
      {
        value: (100 - obj.value) * 0.75,
        arc: arcsGrey[i],
        object: obj
      },
      {
        value: 100 * 0.25,
        arc: arcs[i],
        object: obj
      }
    ];
  });

  var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

  var g = graphGroup.selectAll(null).data(pieData).enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2 + (j * 300)) + ',' + width / 2  + ') rotate(180)');

var thisClass = "g"+String(j);

  var gText = graphGroup.selectAll('.'+thisClass).data([{}]).enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('textClass', true)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2 + (j * 300)) + ',' + width / 2 + ') rotate(180)');




  g.selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
      return pie(d);
    }).enter().append('path')
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
      if (i == 1) {
        return "Text" + d.data.object.label
      }
    })
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return d.data.arc(d);
    }).attr('fill', function(d, i) {
      if (d.data.object.neg == false) {
        return i == 0 ? d.data.object.color : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none';
      } else {
        return i == 0 ? 'red' : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none';
      }
    }).attr('class', 'segments');

  /*
  g.selectAll('.segments').attr('fill', function(d,i) {
    return d.data.object.neg==true ? 'red' : 'none';
  });
  */

  graphGroup.selectAll('g').each(function(d, index) {
    var el = d3.select(this);
    var path = el.selectAll('path').each(function(r, i) {
      if (i === 1) {
        var centroid = r.data.arc.centroid({
          startAngle: r.startAngle + 0.05,
          endAngle: r.startAngle + 0.001 + 0.05
        });
        var lableObj = r.data.object;
        var thisLength = this.getTotalLength();
        g.append('text')
          .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
          .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
          /*.attr('transform', "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + (centroid[1] + 10) + ") rotate(" + (180 / Math.PI * r.startAngle + 7) + ")")
           .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')*/
          .append("textPath")
          .attr("textLength", function(d, i) {
            return 0;
          })
          .attr("xlink:href", "#Text" + r.data.object.label)
          .attr("startOffset", function() {
            return thisLength-22;
            //return index === 2 || index === 5 ? thisLength - 22 : 5
          })
          .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
          .attr("dy", '-3em')
          .text(function(d) {
            if (lableObj.neg == true) {
              return '-' + lableObj.marker;
            } else {
              return lableObj.marker;
            }
          });
      }
      if (i === 0) {
        var centroidText = r.data.arc.centroid({
          startAngle: r.startAngle,
          endAngle: r.startAngle
        });
        var lableObj = r.data.object;
        gText.append('text')
          .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
          .text(lableObj.label)
          .attr('transform', "translate(" + (centroidText[0] - ((1.5 * width) / 100)) + "," + (centroidText[1] + ") rotate(" + (180) + ")"))
          .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central');
      }
    });
  });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

After some help with displaying multiple donut charts using `.selectAll(null)` I have been toiling in vain to remove the text "artifacts" from the 2nd and 3rd chart. The data labels are repeated for some reason, as is visible from the snippet.

What I tried was to create a separate class unique to the current iteration:

```
var thisClass = "g"+String(j);

  var gText = graphGroup.selectAll('.'+thisClass).data([{}]).enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('textClass', true)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2 + (j * 300)) + ',' + width / 2 + ') rotate(180)');
```

### Question

Why is my class-based solution not working as expected? I'm open to other suggestions for getting only the correct data labels to display (rotation doesn't seem to be preserved, not sure why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of d3 internal data iteration rather than iterating on selection yourself.

The solution to your problem is to create a group element for each of your chart that you can iterate on it:

```
 const arcGroup = g
    .selectAll(".group-arc")
    .data(d => pie(d))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "group-arc");
```

This will allow you to append elements to your group based on the number of data obects in the `pie(d)` array, in your case: 3. After that, for each element in the data groups you can append the path (This will add a `path` child to the group.). The result of pie(d) will be an array of 3 data points [start, value, end] for each chart - this will result in iterating 3 times on the `g` element and 3 times more for each `.group-arc` with [start, value, end] as data points.

```
 arcGroup
    .append("path")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
      if (i == 1) {
        return "Text" + d.data.object.label;
      }
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return d.data.arc(d);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      if (d.data.object.neg == false) {
        return i == 0 ? d.data.object.color : i == 1 ? "#D3D3D3" : "none";
      } else {
        return i == 0 ? "red" : i == 1 ? "#D3D3D3" : "none";
      }
    })
```

Next step is to add the text properties. Each data object `d` will be an array of 3 pie elements: start, value, end. You can use the `i` index to know which label you are currently rendering (0 - pie label, 1 - value). The same index can be used to calculate the rotation.

```
arcGroup
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d, i) {
      var lableObj = d.data.object;
      if (i === 0) {
        return lableObj.label;
      } else if (i === 1) {
        if (lableObj.neg === true) {
          return "-" + lableObj.marker;
        } else {
          return lableObj.marker;
        }
      }
    })
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
      var centroidText = d.data.arc.centroid({
        startAngle: d.startAngle,
        endAngle: d.startAngle
      });
      return (
        "translate(" +
        (centroidText[0] - (1.5 * width) / 100) +
        "," +
        (centroidText[1] + ") rotate(" + 180 + ")")
      );
    });
```

or you can use the `.call` method in order to execute code on a single path group:

```
 arcGroup.call(elem => {
    elem.forEach(arcGr => {
      const { parentNode } = arcGr;
      const groupAdd = d3.select(parentNode);
      const arcData = d3.select(arcGr[0]).data();

      groupAdd
        .append("text")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .text(d => d[0].object.label)
        .attr("transform", d => {
          var centroidText = arcData[0].data.arc.centroid({
            startAngle: arcData[0].startAngle,
            endAngle: arcData[0].startAngle
          });
          console.log(centroidText);
          return `translate(${centroidText.join(",")})rotate(180)`;
        });

      groupAdd
        .append("text")
        .text(d => d[1].object.marker)
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "hanging")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-2")
        .attr("transform", d => {
          var path = arcData[0].data.arc(arcData[0]);
          var coords = path.split("L")[1].split("A")[0];
          return `translate(${coords})rotate(180)rotate(${(arcData[0].endAngle *
            180) /
            Math.PI})`;
        });
    });
  });
```

The above implementation might not be the exact desired output but I hope you got the idea how you can simplify your implementation. Also I noticed you are using d3 v3 - you should switch to v5 if possible.

Here is the complete code:

```
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  left: 50,
  bottom: 20,
  right: 20
};

var width = 300;
var arcSize = (6 * width) / 100;
var innerRadius = arcSize * 3;

var extent = 1800;

var data2 = [
  [
    {
      value: (231 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 231,
      label: "Collective",
      color: "#b8cce4",
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (233 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 233,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: "#95b3d7",
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (45 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 45,
      label: "Specific",
      color: "#4f81b9",
      neg: false
    }
  ],

  [
    {
      value: (171 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 171,
      label: "Collective",
      color: "#b8cce4",
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (1712 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 1712,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: "#95b3d7",
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (1 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 1,
      label: "Specific",
      color: "#4f81b9",
      neg: false
    }
  ],

  [
    {
      value: (207 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 207,
      label: "Collective",
      color: "#b8cce4",
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (975 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 975,
      label: "Targeted",
      color: "#95b3d7",
      neg: false
    },
    {
      value: (153 / extent) * 100,
      marker: 153,
      label: "Specific",
      color: "#4f81b9",
      neg: false
    }
  ]
];

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1100 + 100)
  .attr("height", 1100 + 100);

var graphGroup = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
  var data = data2[j];

  var arcs = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return d3.svg
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(i * arcSize + innerRadius)
      .outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - width / 100 + innerRadius);
  });
  var arcsGrey = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return d3.svg
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(i * arcSize + (innerRadius + (arcSize / 2 - 2)))
      .outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - arcSize / 2 + innerRadius);
  });

  var pieData = data.map(function(obj, i) {
    return [
      {
        value: obj.value * 0.75,
        arc: arcs[i],
        object: obj
      },
      {
        value: (100 - obj.value) * 0.75,
        arc: arcsGrey[i],
        object: obj
      },
      {
        value: 100 * 0.25,
        arc: arcs[i],
        object: obj
      }
    ];
  });

  var pie = d3.layout
    .pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });

  var g = graphGroup
    .selectAll(null)
    .data(pieData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + (width / 2 + j * 300) + "," + width / 2 + ") rotate(180)"
    );

  const arcGroup = g
    .selectAll(".group-arc")
    .data(d => pie(d))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "group-arc");

  arcGroup
    .append("path")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
      if (i == 1) {
        return "Text" + d.data.object.label;
      }
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return d.data.arc(d);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      if (d.data.object.neg == false) {
        return i == 0 ? d.data.object.color : i == 1 ? "#D3D3D3" : "none";
      } else {
        return i == 0 ? "red" : i == 1 ? "#D3D3D3" : "none";
      }
    });

 arcGroup.call(elem => {
    elem.forEach(arcGr => {
      const { parentNode } = arcGr;
      const groupAdd = d3.select(parentNode);
      const arcData = d3.select(arcGr[0]).data();

      groupAdd
        .append("text")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .text(d => d[0].object.label)
        .attr("transform", d => {
          var centroidText = arcData[0].data.arc.centroid({
            startAngle: arcData[0].startAngle,
            endAngle: arcData[0].startAngle
          });
          console.log(centroidText);
          return `translate(${centroidText.join(",")})rotate(180)`;
        });

      groupAdd
        .append("text")
        .text(d => d[1].object.marker)
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "hanging")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-2")
        .attr("transform", d => {
          var path = arcData[0].data.arc(arcData[0]);
          var coords = path.split("L")[1].split("A")[0];
          return `translate(${coords})rotate(180)rotate(${(arcData[0].endAngle *
            180) /
            Math.PI})`;
        });
    });
  });


/** 
  //Previous version

  arcGroup
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d, i) {
      var lableObj = d.data.object;
      if (i === 0) {
        return lableObj.label;
      } else if (i === 1) {
        if (lableObj.neg === true) {
          return "-" + lableObj.marker;
        } else {
          return lableObj.marker;
        }
      }
    })
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
      var centroidText = d.data.arc.centroid({
        startAngle: d.startAngle,
        endAngle: d.startAngle
      });
      return (
        "translate(" +
        (centroidText[0] - (1.5 * width) / 100) +
        "," +
        (centroidText[1] + ") rotate(" + 180 + ")")
      );
    });
*/

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. The only issue now is in your implementation the text rotation doesn't seem to be preserved. Any thoughts on why that would be? I can't quite tell why the rotation transform doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the sample with a variant using `.call`.